# PayPal Transaction Search API does not return any result

Tags: paypal

I am calling PayPal API transaction Search [SOAP] from java and getting no results .
Here are my search Parameters  
Transaction start date :- 04-Mar-2012 
InvoiceId :-  '1000010'
However the response is SUCCESS but with NO payment transactions. 
        I checked and this payment is present in my account [ created today ] . 
    Details : 
    1) sdk jar file : "merchant-java-sdk-1.2.95.jar"

```
2) Related properties/configuration file values. 
service.Binding=SOAP
service.RedirectURL=https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/webscr&cmd=
service.DevCentralURL=https://developer.paypal.com

service.EndPoint.PayPalAPI=https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/2.0
service.EndPoint.PayPalAPIAA=https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/2.0
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are currently pointing to sandbox, there is an issue that is preventing the TransactionSearch API from working correctly when searching via the invoice id.  For example if you did a search just based on the start date, you should get results back.

Comment: Thanks for reply . Yeah that works But I really need the filter to work with invoiceid.

Comment: Unfortunately until the issue is resolved, it won't work with the sandbox.  It should be working with the live, just not Sandbox. The last information I had on this, was that it should be fixed by the end of March.  However, keep in mind that this date could be moved up or pushed back at any time.  I would suggest opening up a ticket with PayPal MTS at www.paypal.com/mts if you would like to be notified once the issue is resolved.

Comment: Thanks for your fast response. I already opened a ticket on www.paypal.com/mts couple of days ago . Haven`t got any response yet. Another thing is there was an email sent to me stating "Your question has been received. To review the status of your ticket, click on the link below. " However there is no link in the email .

Comment: Thanks!  I will grab your ticket and get it associated with the bug for this, that way you will be notified once the issue is resolved.