# PayPal Payments API does not return any payments

Tags: c#, paypal

I have a paypal account with linked bank account. I've created REST Api app called "spbpriest". Using PayPal .NET SDK I've created simple application which returns payments list for bank account using Payment.List method. Unfortunately method returns zero payments. Should I link REST API app to bank account somehow to receive real payment?

Code example:

```
    var config = ConfigManager.Instance.GetProperties();

    // Use OAuthTokenCredential to request an access token from PayPal
    var accessToken = new OAuthTokenCredential(config).GetAccessToken();
    var apiContext = new APIContext(accessToken);

    apiContext.Config = ConfigManager.Instance.GetProperties();

    // Define any custom configuration settings for calls that will use this object.
    apiContext.Config["connectionTimeout"] = "100000";
    var payments = Payment.List(apiContext, count: 10, startIndex:0, sortBy: "create_time", sortOrder: "desc");
```

app.config:

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="paypal" type="PayPal.SDKConfigHandler, PayPal" />
  </configSections>
  <paypal>
    <settings>
      <add name="mode" value="sandbox"/>
      <add name="clientId" value="******"/>
      <add name="clientSecret" value="******"/>
    </settings>
  </paypal>
</configuration>
```

[image: PayPal developers page description]

Comment: your problem is that it don't trigger or it trigger but is empty?

Comment: possible duplicate of this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15211490/paypal-transaction-search-api-does-not-return-any-result?rq=1

Comment: The response is successfull but list of payments is empty

Comment: I've tried to switch to "live" mode and still received empty list of payments. I've also tried to receive list of bank accounts **var accounts = BankAccount.List(apiContext);**. And the list was empty again.